# Google Cloud Messaging service in flex mobile project

Tags: air, google-cloud-messaging, flex-mobile, air-native-extension

I,m in process of developing GCM service in flex mobile project. I want to clear some things initialy.

1- I came up to some tutorials that help in achieving the task, but they require me to download their native extension (.ane file) and add it to the project lib and use it to achieve the task. what is this .ane file used for?

2- can i use the GCM service in flex mobile project without such .ane file?

kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need an ANE - unless Adobe extends [flash.notifications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-push-notifications.html) one day to support Android too.

Answer (score 0):

Az Alex said, you need an ANE because Adobe road map says that they will consentrate mainly on the Air itself and developers should build the extensions themselves... http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html

for a GCM extension, I would suggest you to take a look at http://myappsnippet.com/gcm which supports custom notification icons and sounds...